# If statement ignoring condition

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int binary_to_decimal(int n){
    int ostatok, i=0, pom, decimal=0;
    pom=n;
    while(pom)
    {
        ostatok=pom%10;
        decimal+=ostatok*pow(2,i);
        pom/=10;
        i++;
    }
    return decimal;
}

int main()
{
    int m, n, i, max=0, number;
    scanf(" %d %d", &n, &m);
    int array[n];

    for(i=0; i<n ;i++){
        scanf(" %d", &number);
        binary_to_decimal(number);
        if(number>m) // this if statement doesn't seem to be doing it's job
            array[i]=number;
        if(array[i]>max)
            max=array[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<n ;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d %d\n", array[i], binary_to_decimal(array[i]));
    }
    printf("Max %d %d", max,  binary_to_decimal(max));
    return 0;
}
```

The program is: you enter two `int` values, `m` and `n`. `m` is used as a value for comparison, while `n` is the number of binary number the user is inputting in the loop. If the inputted number is greater than the number `m` print out  the values of the inputted number in binary then in decimal. At the end, print out the number with the biggest value in binary and decimal.
My problem is the `if` where i am comparing `m` and the inputted number and i can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: `binary_to_decimal(number);` this has no effect at all.

Comment: Add `printf("%d > %d?\n", number, m);` above `if(number>m)`?

Comment: My guess is that you need to write `number = binary_to_decimal(number);` otherwise you compare the binary representation to the decimal one.

Comment: `array[i]` only gets a value if `number>m`.  That's conditional.  But it is used unconditionally.  Results are undefined.  It's not an answer to your question, but is an additional problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @Osiris i can't use `number = binary_to_decimal(number);` because when i overwrite the value of number i get some random number

Comment: @Spyware If you get `some random number` then maybe your `binary_to_decimal` function is broken.

Comment: Note that the whole concept of a `binary_to_decimal` that returns an `int` is questionable.  Type `int` has a binary representation, period.  You can encode decimal digits in it an a non-native way, but you cannot then interpret the result as a normal `int`.

Comment: @Osiris it's not, i'm running it on a separate c project, works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The call binary_to_decimal(number) does not change your number.
Try something like:

```
number = binary_to_decimal(number);
```

Comment: C does not have references

Comment: `int &n` is C++, not C.

Comment: And your function never changes `n`.